# Can lost update problem in REST APIs prevented with Database transactions alone?

Tags: database, rest, concurrency, transactions, optimistic-concurrency

Can lost updates be prevented at REST APIs by only requiring a DB transaction (at repeatable read or Snapshot isolation) ?

What if the user GETs a version and then updates an attribute and sends a PUT request but meanwhile some other user has changed the same attribute and successfully completed the PUT (also DB update) ? Assume such a case cannot be prevented DB transaction alone?

In this case we additionally need an optimistic concurrency control mechanism at the application layer (say using version number or Etags) ?

If we do have an optimistic control at application layer, do we then need transaction (since single row update with `WHERE version = v1` would automatically prevent lost updates) unless updating multiple tables?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question?